# prove that solution of E-L is the minimizer of a functional on a cylinder

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Q: Find the geodesic on the circular cylinder of radius 1.

My try: Consider the cylindrical coordinates $(\theta,z)$. Fix two points on the cylinder $x_0=(\theta_0,z_0),x_1(\theta_1,z_1)$. Then the functional can be written as 
$$
J(\gamma)=\int_0^1\sqrt{\dot{\theta}(t)^2+\dot{z}(t)^2}dt
$$
where $\gamma\in U=\{x\in C^1([0,1],\text{cylinder}); x(0)=(\theta_0,z_0),x(1)=(\theta_1,z_1)\}$.

By using the E-L  equation, we can find that 
$$
\gamma^*(t):\begin{cases}
\theta=(\theta_1-\theta_0)t+\theta_0\\
z=(z_1-z_0)t+z_0
\end{cases}
$$
Now we need to show that the solution of E-L equation is the minimizer of functional. To prove this, we need to check the second derivative (variation) of functional $J$ at $\gamma^*$ is strongly derivative, that is 
$$
J''(\gamma^*)(h,h)\geq k\Vert h\Vert^2,\forall h\in U
$$
where $k$ is postive constant.

Let $h=(h_1,h_2)\in U$, we have 
$$
J''(\gamma^*)(h,h)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{((\theta_1-\theta_0 )^2+(z_1-z_0 )^2)^{3/2}}\int_0^1[(z_1-z_0)\dot{h}_1- (\theta_1-\theta_0 )\dot{h}_2]^2dt
$$
I don't know how to continue